# How to make react-select searchable always show clear indicator

Tags: react-select

Actually, clear indicator only show when value has selected, i want to show up this when any value has type.

The reason is simple, easy clear current value search typed.

Comment: i'm thinking to omit clearable and pass a custom dropdown indicator, turning into a clear indicator when user types

Answer (score 3):

One solution to your problem is to use `state` to store the `inputValue` as `value` like the following code:

```
  onChange = (option, { action }) => {
    if (action === "clear") {
      this.setState({
        value: null
      });
    }

    if (action === "select-option") {
      this.setState({
        value: option
      });
    }
  };

  onInputChange = (string, { action }) => {
    if (action === "input-change") {
      this.setState({
        value: { value: string, label: string }
      });
    }

    if (action === "menu-close") {
      this.setState({
        value: null
      });
    }
  };
```

You can see with this piece of code:

```
    if (action === "input-change") {
      this.setState({
        value: { value: string, label: string }
      });
    }
```

That you fake a value and as every time a value is set the `clear` function is enabled, it does the trick. You can find a live version of this code [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-select-clearable-inputvalue-22dkx).

Answer (score 0):

```
  const [value, setValue] = useState<any>(null)

  const onChange = (option: any, { action } : {action: any}) => {
    if (action === "clear") {
      setValue(null)
    }

    if (action === "select-option") {
     setValue(option)
    }
  };

  const onInputChange = (string: any, { action }: {action: any}) => {
    if (action === "input-change") {
      setValue({ value: string, label: string });
    }

    if (action === "menu-close") {
      setValue(null)
    }
  };
```